# Is there a way to restore a BigQuery table to an earlier state?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to restore a Bigquery table to an earlier state like the state at a timestamp?

Per https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax,
they mentioned they can return a historical version of the table.
"
The following query returns a historical version of the table at an absolute point in time.

SELECT *
FROM t
FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '2017-01-01 10:00:00-07:00';
".

If a restore statement is available in BigQuery, then I think I can capture SYSTEM_TIME and restore a table to that timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

One of the options would be to delete current table and create a new one with `CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT * FROM t FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '2017-01-01 10:00:00-07:00'`

Comment: Thank you Sergey for the kind reply. Then the procedure would be 1. create a temporary table with the above syntax as of the old timestamp, 2. drop original table. 3. rename the temporary table to original table. But my concern for this procedure is that we need 2xN size for size N original table. My questions are: 1. Is there a way to delete only the delta rows between T1 and T2 (where T1 is the old timestamp to go back to, T2 is current timestamp)? maybe using rowid or something?

Comment: Sure, BigQuery has a [DELETE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#delete_statement) statement. Also you can try deleting a table and then [recovering it from a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#undeletetable).